# Moments of Particular System of Stochastic Differential Equations (SDEs)

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I have reduced an Ito diffusion process to the following:
$$
  dX^i_s = \sigma_j^i(X_s) \,dB_s^j
$$
where $i,j$ are the indices of the components and $\sigma$ is derived from the inverse metric tensor (which was only a function of the $z$ coordinate). Note there is no drift term.

Expanded out, my system is given by:
\begin{aligned}
  dX^1_s &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ 
              (a+b\cos(c X^3_s))dB^1_s + b\sin(cX^3_s)dB^2_s 
              \right]\\
  dX^2_s &= \frac{1}{2}\left[ 
              (a-b\cos(c X^3_s))dB^2_s + b\sin(cX^3_s)dB^1_s 
              \right]\\
  dX^3_s &= \frac{k}{2}\, dB^3_s
\end{aligned}
where $a,b,c,k$ are real, positive constants. (Also, the superscripts are of course indices, not powers.)

My naive solution attempt is to first integrate equation 3, giving:
$$
   X^3_s = {k} B^3_s
$$
Now I'll let $X_0^i=0\;\forall\; i$. 
Then, by (blind) substitution and integration, the first two equations become:
$$
   2X_t^1 = aB^1_t + b\int\limits_0^t\cos(ck B^3_s/2)\,dB^1_s
             + b\int\limits_0^t\sin(ck B^3_s/2)\,dB^2_s 
$$
$$
   2X_t^2 = aB^2_t + b\int\limits_0^t\sin(ck B^3_s/2)\,dB^1_s
             - b\int\limits_0^t\cos(ck B^3_s/2)\,dB^2_s 
$$
I do not know how to proceed from here (or whether the prior steps are correct). 
I would like to compute $X_t=(X_t^1,X_t^2,X_t^3)$, but $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]$ would be great too. 
Ito's isometry and formula are not helping me, because I need to integrate a Brownian motion term with respect to an independent Brownian motion term.

If there is an obvious mistake or solution, please forgive me, as I have only just starting reading in this area. Any literature or tutorials about this would be appreciated too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, not that I want to answer my own question, but I seem to have been able to work out the first two moments at least.

**Lemmas/Facts**

---

Let $\{B^i\}$ and $\{W^i\}$ be standard independent Brownian motions.

$\mathbb{E}[B_t^i] = 0$, $\;\mathbb{E}[(B_t^i)^2] = t$, 
$\;(B_{t+k}^i-B_{t}^i)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,k)$. [1]

If $\theta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, $\;\mathbb{E}[\sin(\theta)] = 0$ and
$\;\mathbb{E}[\cos(\theta)] = \exp(-\sigma^2/2)$.
Further, $\mathbb{E}[\cos^2(\theta)] = (1/2 + \exp(-2\sigma^2)/2)$ using $\cos^2(\theta)=(1+\cos(2\theta))/2$.
 [2]

The Ito isometry [3]: 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
  \left(
    \int_0^T X_t\, dW_t
  \right)^2
\right]
=
\mathbb{E}\left[
  \int_0^T X_t^2 dt
\right]
$$
and a corollary with two functions and Fubini [4]:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
  \left(
    \int_0^T f(s)\, dW_s
  \right)
\left(
    \int_0^T g(s)\, dW_s
  \right)
\right]
=
  \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[f(s) g(s)] dt
$$
and another corollary [5]:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
 W_t
\left(
    \int_0^t g(s)\, dW_s
  \right)
\right]
=
  \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[g(s)] ds
$$

Also, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863933/expectation-of-product-of-ito-integrals-wrt-independent-brownian-motions) for why [6]:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
  \left(
    \int_0^T f(s,B_s)\, dW^j_s
  \right)
\left(
    \int_0^T g(s,B_s)\, dW^i_s
  \right)
\right]
=
0
$$ when $i\ne j$.

**First Moments**

---

Turns out this is pretty easy. Using [1] and the fact that the integrals all vanish under expectation (because the integrand only ever depends on a Wiener process independent from the one in the differential), we get:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[
    X_t
   \right] = \vec{0}
$$
This seems reasonable, given the diffusion has no drift.

**Second Moments**

---

This one is a bit longer. The easy case using [2]:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[
   (X_t^3)^2
  \right] = {k^2}\mathbb{E}\left[
   (B_t^3)^2
  \right] = k^2 t
$$
Let's do $X_t^2$ now.
$$
  \left(
    a B_t^2 + b\int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1 - b\int\limits_0^t \cos(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^2
  \right)^2
=
a^2 (B_t^2)^2 
+ 
2ab B^2_t \int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1
-
2ab B^2_t \int\limits_0^t \cos(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^2
- 
2b^2 \left(
\int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1 
\right)\left(
\int\limits_0^t \cos(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^2
\right)
+
b^2
\left(
\int\limits_0^t \cos(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^2
\right)^2
+
b^2
\left(
\int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1 
\right)^2
$$
Now let's go term-by-term.
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[
    a^2 (B_t^2)^2 
  \right] = a^2 t
$$
By independence and [1]:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
    2ab B^2_t \int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1
  \right]
=
2ab\mathbb{E}\left[
    B^2_t\right] 
\mathbb{E}\left[\int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1
  \right] = 0
$$
Using [2] and [5]:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[
    -2ab B^2_t \int\limits_0^t \cos(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^2
  \right]
  =
  -2ab\int\limits_0^t\mathbb{E}\left[\cos(ckB^3_s/2)\right]ds
  =
  -2ab\frac{8}{c^2k^2}\left[ 1 - \exp(c^2k^2t/8) \right]
$$
Using [6]:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[
    - 
2b^2 \left(
\int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1 
\right)\left(
\int\limits_0^t \cos(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^2
\right)
  \right] = 0
$$
Using [2] and $\cos^2(\theta)=1-\sin^2(\theta)$:
$$
  \mathbb{E}\left[
    b^2 \left(
\int\limits_0^t \sin(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^1 
\right)^2
  \right]
=
b^2 \int\limits_0^t  
\mathbb{E}\left[
\sin^2(ckB^3_s/2)
\right]ds
=
b^2\left(
  \frac{t}{2} - \frac{1}{c^2k^2}\left[ 1 - \exp(-c^2k^2t/2) \right]
\right)
$$
For the same reasons:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
    b^2 \left(
\int\limits_0^t \cos(ckB^3_s/2)\,dB_s^2 
\right)^2
  \right]
=
b^2\left(
  \frac{t}{2} + \frac{1}{c^2k^2}\left[ 1 - \exp(-c^2k^2t/2) \right]
\right)
$$
Summing the expectations gives:
$$
 \mathbb{E}\left[
   (X^2_t)^2
 \right]
=
\frac{1}{4}\left[
  (a^2 + b^2)t - \frac{16ab}{c^2k^2}\left( 1 - \exp(-c^2k^2t/8) \right)
\right]
$$
The other component is almost the same:
$$
 \mathbb{E}\left[
   (X^1_t)^2
 \right]
=
\frac{1}{4}\left[
  (a^2 + b^2)t + \frac{16ab}{c^2k^2}\left( 1 - \exp(-c^2k^2t/8) \right)
\right]
$$
Given the first moment values, the variance is then:
$$
  \mathbb{V}[X_t]
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 (a^2 + b^2)t + \frac{16ab}{c^2k^2}\left( 1 - \exp(-c^2k^2t/8) \right) \\
(a^2 + b^2)t - \frac{16ab}{c^2k^2}\left( 1 - \exp(-c^2k^2t/8) \right)\\
k^2 t
\end{bmatrix}
$$